# FCM API Bad Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase, google-api, firebase-cloud-messaging, httprequest

I'm trying to push a notification through FCM from my Ruby on Rails project, here is my code:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

def send_notifications
 log = Logger.new("log/notifications.log")
 begin
  uri = URI.parse("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

  http.use_ssl = true
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

  key = '...'
  hash = {:notification => {:sound =>  "default", :title => "test", :text => "test", :badge => "0"}, :data => {:targetID => "1", :to => "..."}}

req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Authorization' => "key=#{key}"})
req.body = hash.to_json
response = http.request(req)
log.debug("response #{response.body}")
rescue => e
  log.debug("failed #{e}")
 end
end
```

I'm getting Bad Request 400 error, and debugging the response body only shows this: "to"

Please help me debug this issue. Thank you

Comment: Can you try this ? `request = HTTParty.post('http://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', :body => { "to" => "token", "data" => { "title" =>title, "body"=>message, 'message_type'=>'text'}}.to_json, :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Authorization' => "key=#{server_token}" } )`. You can re-frame it using `Net::HTTP`.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna I tried the following:       req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, :body => hash.to_json, :headers => {"Content-Type" => "application/json", "Authorization" => "key=#{key}"})
 but I got this error: undefined method `downcase' for :body:Symbol

Comment: Can you try it with `HTTParty` ?

Comment: I installed httparty 0.2.0 since I have Ruby 1.8.7 but I got this error: uninitialized constant Net::HTTParty though I added require 'httparty'

Comment: Can you make changes as per [this](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/71eb0)

Comment: I wasn't able to install pry do to my ruby version, I also tried old pry versions but non of them worked.

Comment: Ok. Apart from the `pry` did the request work ?

Comment: No, it is still giving the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179976/discussion-between-kedarnag-mukanahallipatna-and-user3640056).